# Heroku Dyno/Worker Scaling

Tags: heroku, scalability

Heroku allows you to add and remove dynos and workers on the fly and charges you per second that each is used. Is it possible to set up my app so that it can add/remove dynos and workers from itself depending on the load it's under via some sort of heroku api?

Answer (score 6):

For scaling worker dynos:

- https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire - open source
- http://hirefireapp.com/ - service in public beta now

Comment: HireFire now supports both web and worker dynos, and the service is out of beta.

Comment: Is there a python equivalent of this?

Comment: @Anthony Roberts: See http://hirefire.io/documentation/guides/getting-started - there is some out-of-the-box Python support. Additionally you can get it to work with any language really: http://hirefire.io/documentation/guides/all-language-integration

Comment: Thanks Michael.  But between posting this and now I've got it set up and working great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Check out

http://github.com/ddollar/heroku-autoscale
http://github.com/pedro/delayed_job/tree/autoscaling

Comment: `heroku-autoscale` is now depracated

Answer (score 2):

If you dont want to include a gem, there is an addon for this:
https://addons.heroku.com/adept-scale

Comment: This add-on works only for web dynos, not for workers.

Answer (score -1):

As of 2018, the only add-on available that autoscales for both web dynos and worker dynos seems to be IronWorker.

I haven't tried it, but looks good:
https://elements.heroku.com/addons/iron_worker

[HireFire](https://www.hirefire.io/) seems to be still available as well, but not directly as an add-on through Heroku's platform.